# No logro leer la cookie enviada desde el backend

Tags: express, cookies, setcookie

estoy intentando acceder a una cookie desde el back (PORT=3001) para leerla en el front pero siempre me figura vacio

```
const token = await generateToken(user._id)


    res.cookie('token', token, { sameSite: 'lax' })

    res.json({ token, user })
```

Aca intento recuperarla:

```
export const validateToken = (req, res, next) => {
   

    const token = req.cookies.token
    console.log(token);
```

Habia visto que samesite: 'lax' te permitia acceder a las cookies de cualquier otro puerto, pero sigo sin poder verla

Estoy intentando acceder a una cookie desde el front enviada por el back